# numpy multiple matrix multiplication

Tags: numpy, scipy

If I have a matrix product like $(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$, is the way to write this for numpy arrays would be `reduce(numpy.dot,((x-mu).T, scipy.linalg.inv(Sigma), x-mu))`? Matlab and R syntax is so much simpler that it seems a bit odd for numpy to not have an equivalent operator syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try:

```
x = x.view(np.matrix)
isigma = scipy.linalg.inv(Sigma).view(np.matrix)
result = (x-mu).T * isigma * (x-mu)
```

By taking a view of your arrays as matrices, you get to use the `.__mul__` operator of `np.matrix` which performs your matrix multiplication when you use `*`.

Comment: There is no memory overhead because `view` doesn't create new objects, if I remember correctly?

Comment: @crippledlambda : exactly, that's the beauty of `view`. The memory space was already allocated, you just present it differently.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `*` is already defined as elementwise multiplication for numpy arrays, and there is no other obvious operator left for matrix multiplication. The solution, as Pierre suggests, is to convert to numpy matrices, where `*` means matrix multiplication.

There have been a few proposals to add new operator types to Python ([PEP 225](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0225/), for example) which would allow something like `~*` to represent matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write (Numpy >= 1.4 or so)

```
from scipy.linalg import inv

(x - mu).T.dot(inv(Sigma)).dot(x - mu)
```

As mentioned in the other answer, the limited operator syntax is due to the restricted number of operators available in Python.